# SQL Count - Calculate months

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

Can someone help me to get sum of months from below data in SQL?

**Data:**

| Name | Start_Dt | End_Dt | Months |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-01 | 6 |
| 1234 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-08-31 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-12-31 | 4 |
| 1234 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-07-31 | 7 |
| 1235 | 2021-09-01 | 2021-12-31 | 4 |
| 1235 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-06-30 | 6 |
| 1235 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-08-31 | 8 |

Using above data, I'm trying to get the Total_Mo count by min(Start_dt) and max(End_Dt).

**Output:**

| Name | Start_Dt | End_Dt | Total_Mo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 12 |
| 1235 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-12-31 | 12 |

Thank you

Comment: Hi Austin,
I'm using SQL server, and Start_Dt and End_Dt is YYYY-MM-DD format.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Its Date datatype, not int.

Comment: What do you mean by "sum of months"? How are you calculating 11 and 12 in your desired output?

Comment: Hi - as this is not a free code writing service, please update your question with what you’ve managed to write on your own and explain the specific issue you are facing

Comment: Rephrased the question and output.

Comment: I'm guessing the "months" column in your data is irrelevant here. So are you basically wanting to calculate the date_diff (in months) between the min(start_date) and max(end_date) for each name? Update your question with these relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your recent edit it looks like you require an aggregate as follows and the use of *datediff*:

```
select Name, Min(Start_dt) Start_Dt, Max(End_dt) End_Dt,
    DateDiff(month, Min(Start_dt), Max(End_dt)) + 1 Total_no
from t
group by Name;
```

Note you have to add 1 to the count since *datediff* counts the number of date *boundaries* crossed by the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, Start_Dt, End_Dt,
SUM(DATEDIFF(MONTH, Start_Dt, End_Dt) + 1) AS Total_Mo
FROM
(
  SELECT Name, 
  MIN(Start_Dt) AS Start_Dt, 
  MAX(End_Dt) AS End_Dt
  FROM YourTable
) as z
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean the difference and not the sum of months?

i.e. EDIT: Took out `CAST(` per comment to clarify type as DATE

```
DECLARE @Samples TABLE (
    DataName VARCHAR(10),
    Start_Dt DATE,
    End_Dt DATE,
    Months INT);

INSERT INTO @Samples (
    DataName,
    Start_Dt,
    End_Dt,
    Months
)
SELECT
    DataName,
    Start_Dt,
    End_Dt,
    Months 
FROM (
VALUES
('1234', '2021-01-01', '2021-06-01', 6),
('1234', '2021-08-01', '2021-08-31', 1),
('1234', '2021-09-01', '2021-12-31', 4),
('1234', '2021-01-01', '2021-07-31', 7),
('1235', '2021-09-01', '2021-12-31', 4),
('1235', '2021-01-01', '2021-06-30', 6),
('1235', '2021-01-01', '2021-08-31', 8)
) AS V (DataName,Start_Dt,End_Dt,Months);

SELECT 
    DataName,
    MIN(Start_Dt) AS MinDate,
    MAX(End_Dt) AS MaxDate,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(Start_Dt ), MAX(End_Dt)) +1 AS DiffMonths
FROM @Samples
GROUP BY DataName;
```

Sample output

```
DataName    MinDate MaxDate DiffMonths
1234    2021-01-01  2021-12-31  12
1235    2021-01-01  2021-12-31  12
```